# Receive invalid data with TCP socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming

this is my server side code for sending data to client:

```
public bool SendMessage(Socket socket, byte[] message, string logMessage = "Unknow")
    {
        try
        {
            MsgTemp msg = new MsgTemp(socket, logMessage, message);

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(" send ---------- " + message.Length.ToString());

            socket.BeginSend(message, 0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), msg /* null*/);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            // :) removed
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and this code is receive callback method in client:

```
private void ReceiverCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int size = _socket.EndReceive(ar);
            _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiverCallBack), null);

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(" received ---------- " + size.ToString());

            // messagereceived is an event
            if (MessageReceived != null)
            {
                byte[] temp = new byte[size];
                Array.Copy(_buffer, temp, size);

                MessageReceived(temp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            // :) removed
        }

    }
```

when server send many packages to client data goes invalid.
(in normal/low transaction work correctly)

see this (bytes was sent between server an client in a conversation) :

```
send ---------- 496 
received ---------- 496
send ---------- 613
received ---------- 613
send ---------- 680
received ---------- 680
send ---------- 227
send ---------- 697
received ---------- 227
send ---------- 722
send ---------- 710
received ---------- 697
received ---------- 1432
```

two last packages was sent to client received in one package -> 722 + 710 = 1432
and data goes invalid/unusable...

why ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how TCP works - it's a *stream* protocol. The bytes are guaranteed to be received in exactly the order they are sent, but you can `Receive` the data of multiple `Send` operations at once, or receive the data of one `Send` operation in two `Receive`s.

You'll have to somehow define what a message is - it's common to first send the size of a message, followed by the message payload.

See for example http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html - it contains a good explanation of the why, the how and code examples. There are many other examples available online.

Comment: your solution is, first send message size must client receive then send data/bytes ?

Comment: @warrior I don't like providing paste-ready solutions, but yes that's the best approach if you ask me. The blog link I posted contains a link to an example: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html

Comment: thank you, that article is very good..., he had the same problem.